# Ошибка при выделении строки QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

Нужно добавить строку и программа падает при попытке выделить ее, то есть тут 
        `// Выделяем добавленную запись;
        ui.table->setCurrentCell(insertPos, 0);`

Если я убираю строку, то строка добавляется в браузер но при попытке выделить ее в браузере программа так же падает

```
    // Добавляем в браузер новую строку
    ui.table->insertRow(insertPos);

    QTableWidgetItem *item;

    // Записываем в добавленную строку информацию о книге
    // Записываем в 1-ю ячейку название модели
    item = new QTableWidgetItem(other.name);
    ui.table->setItem(insertPos, 0, item);

    // Записываем вo 2-ю ячейку цену модели
    QString cost1 = QString::number(other.cost);    //конвернтировать int в QString
    item = new QTableWidgetItem(cost1);
    ui.table->setItem(insertPos, 1, item);

    //записываем уникальный индетификатор в первуц колонку
    ui.table->item(insertPos, 0)->setData(Qt::UserRole, other.id);

    // Выделяем добавленную запись;
    ui.table->setCurrentCell(insertPos, 0);
```

Comment: Самое интересное то, что если три записи будет, то все ок, а если 2, то все, при попытке выделить падает

Comment: Гляньте по стек-трейсу, в каком месте падает. А то в приведенном коде вроде как все в порядке.

Comment: К сигналу изменения текущего элемента что-нибудь присоединено?

Comment: Я таким методом отладки впервые встретился. Почитал в интернете и понял. В стеке каким то образом мои функции оказались, попробую посмотреть что там не так.

Comment: Действительно нужно было проверить по стек-трейсу. По ошибке в какой то функции у меня переменная (Идентификатор) пыталась получить значение от несуществующей третьей колонки. Исправил и все заработало.